# Greasemonkey (Violentmonkey) script to change website value

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I want to modify the layou of a website:

```
<div id="fluid_video_wrapper_video-id" class="fluid_video_wrapper fluid_player_layout_default" style="height: 150px; width: 300px;">
```

And change "**style**" to "**height: "1080px; width: 1920px;**"

Im trying this script, but doesnt work:

```
var query = document.querySelector("#fluid_video_wrapper_video-id");
if (query) {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        query.setAttribute("style", "height: 1080px; width: 1920px;");
      
    }, 500)
}
```

Whats wrong with it?

Comment: You're setting the style once every 1/2 second. That doesn't sound necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a simple `document.getElementById`? Try the below code, and see if it helps. If the setTimeout() had a specific purpose, feel free to include it.

```js
//grab the id of the div
const modify = document.getElementById('fluid_video_wrapper_video-id');

//if it exists
if (modify) {
     //style the width and height
     modify.style.height = '1080px';
     modify.style.width = '1920px';
}
```

Hope it helps you out!

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. To give further explanation, if I left click the video thumbnail, it opens a new tab and the size of the videoplayer is the native size of the video (usually 1080p, sometimes 720p).  But if I middle click, the video size is 300x150p.  I want to middle click because this way I dont lose focus from the main window.

Comment: It sounds like their may be conflicting styling in the css. Maybe the !important attribute will help? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp. Tell me if it works!

Comment: I added !important:  but didnt work either.  I also noticed left clicking doesnt always open the video at native resolution.

Comment: See @James D answer, then. See if you are actually changing the right element using this method. You know it is something else changing it if when you uncheck the styling box, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try inspecting the element.  On the Elements tab go the the Styles tab. From there you should find a checkbox for all the different CSS style rules that are being applied.  Try unchecking the one you do not want and build your script from there.